# When creating a new block in EPiServer, how can the block type order be changed?

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

The *New block* view in EPiServer 7.5 displays block groups and block types inside the groups in a seemingly random order.

This screenshot from the Alloy demo site shows the issue:

[image: Screenshot: creating a new block. The block groups and block types are displayed in a random order?]

I'd like to display the block types inside the groups in alphabetical order to make finding the correct block type easier. It would be great if the groups could also be ordered. E.g.

- Default

  - ButtonBlock
  - ContactBlock
  - PageListBlock
  - TeaserBlock
- Information
- Optimization
- Specialized

Is this possible in EPiServer 7.5? How are the groups and types ordered by default?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in EPiServer 8, not in 7.5 unfortunately. Please see this blog post http://world.episerver.com/blogs/Per-Bjurstrom/2015/2/typed-tabsgroups/

```
[GroupDefinitions]
public static class GroupNames
{
   [Display(GroupName="MyNews", Order=1)]
   public const string News = "News";

   [RequiredAccess(AccessLevel.Publish)]
   public const string Contact= "Contact";
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is about the sort order of the blocks *within* the groups, not the groups themselves?

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, as @TedNyberg said, I'm more interested in sort order of the block types themselves. The link provides an answer to that, too: `[ContentType(Order=1)]`. Now I'm just left wondering how I can easily keep my types alphabetized when there are dozens of them...

Comment: Saidly I do not think that is possible, will have to add it as a feature request.
I think that it would be good to be able to have a setting that tells EPiServer to default sort on alphabetic order (asc or desc) or by sortorder.

I will add it as a feature request

Comment: Now there is a feature request registered:
http://world.episerver.com/forum/developer-forum/Feature-requests/Thread-Container/2015/5/set-default-sort-order-for-groups-and-inside-groups-with-contenttypes/